# Call a flow in apex REST

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, flow

I need to call a flow, to create or update an sObject, in my REST class :

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/object')
  global with sharing class RESTObject{
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    String eventId = req.params.get('eventId');
    Event ev;

    if(eventId == null){
      //some code here
    }
    else{
      ev = [SELECT Id, Obj_Id__c FROM Event WHERE Id=:eventId];
      if(ev.Obj_Id__c == null){
            Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
            params.put('EventId', eventId);

            Flow.Interview.CreateEventE flow = new Flow.Interview.CreateEventE(params);
            flow.start();

            String comId = (String) flow.getVariableValue('comId');

            try {
                update new Commande__c(Id = comId , RecordTypeId = rt.Id);
            } catch (DMLException e) {
                //System.debug('#### ' + e);
                return null;
            }
            return ev.Obj_Id__c;
    }
    else{ 
       //some code here
    }
}
```

When I try this in the workbench, using the Id of an event with a null `Obj_Id__c`, I get an error at the line `flow.start();` and at the line with the update.

How can I fix that ?

**EDIT**

The error is:

> System.FlowException : 
>   An unhandled error occurred in this flow An unhandled error occurred while processing the flow.

And it indicates me the line with the `start()`.

I also get a mail each time I try to run the flow that give me the

> INSERT --- INSERT FAILED --- ERRORS : (FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION)

**EDIT 2 : after remove the filter on my field**
[image]

Comment: Is this a part of your class? Does it work with out a method?

Comment: Please paste the error that you are getting.

Comment: @Saumya Ranjan Satapathy I edited my question

Answer (score 2):

FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION clearly suggests that in your flow there is a failure in the insertion of record due to Validations on the field .This may be due to a lookup filters on one of the fields of record  your flow is trying to insert .

Verify that flow is receiving all the parameters and field values it needs for proper functioning .

Comment: There is a filter on a object, I disable it to try and there is no longer error, but when I run the url on workbench, I get "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" and it don't return what I expected (`ev.Obj_Id__c` which is "null" in my case) is that normal ?

Comment: Hi @Mohith Shrivastava I have updated my question to add the picture of what I get

Comment: You are getting 200 Status code which means your service is running now .dig through logs to see variable values .Hope that helps

Comment: Ok thanks @Mohith Shrivastava ! I also have another question : if I want to test a null value : `eventId = null` when I try this url "/services/apexrest/object" in the workbench it thows me an error "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object" but the point is to test a null object... I don't see how test that case